# SDL strange linker error in MVS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl, linker-errors

I'm stumped trying to link the SDL libraries against a new C++ Win32 Console application in MVS 2010.

I downloaded the latest SDL development libraries, and did the usual steps:

1. Added the includes to the include path ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd8iv.png)) [This works fine, as MVS finds the #include files]
2. Added the library path for SDL ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uTUa.png)) [This seems to work fine, as removing this additional path gives the error "error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL.lib'"]
3. Added SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib to the linker additional dependencies ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OKc8.png))

I edited the main file to have some test code, leaving it looking like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int a;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

std::cout << "Pong" << std::endl;
std::cin >> a;

return 0;
}
```

And when I compile I get the following linker errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _wmain   D:\All\Proyects\PFC\RT-Pong\RT-Pong\RT-Pong\RT-Pong.obj RT-Pong
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\All\Proyects\PFC\RT-Pong\RT-Pong\Debug\RT-Pong.exe   1   1   RT-Pong
```

In case I had a corrupted .lib, I downloaded the whole thing again, starting from 0, and got the same result. I'm honestly stumped, and it reeks of being a careless simple mistake that I'm overlooking. So if anyone has some fresh input on the matter, it would really make my day.

Thanks,
Jaime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got linking error due to "wrong path defined at library path for SDL"

At `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

Change the path from this: `D:\All\Proyects\PFC\RT-Pong\SDL-1.2.15\lib\x64`

Into this: `D:\All\Proyects\PFC\RT-Pong\SDL-1.2.15\lib\x86`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was under the impression the .lib files in x86 where for 32 bit systems, and the ones in x64 where for 64 bit systems, and I'm working with a 64b machine, so linking to the 64b folder seemed the reasonable idea.

Comment: Your system is 64bit But your program is not 64bit, actually your program is 32bit so it uses the 32bit Library.I'm also working on 64bit machine but I am using only 32bit library because my program is related to 32bit. you can see the snapshot on my system for proof..... http://i.imgur.com/6zKbe.png?1

Comment: And it works. You where right. Thank you for your help :) When are the x64 lib files supposed to be used then? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Switch:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Set in project properties to "console application"

Read this: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but none of the above fixed my problem. I followed lazy foo's tutorial step by step and still got the same problems. Tried in MVS 2008 as well, just in case, and got the same. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are linking to the lib files and make sure the SDL.dll is in your system32 or sysWOW64(for x64 pc) or directory you are running the program from folder, if you are not sure they are linked you can use the following to link it and make sure your project is set to console.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "SDLmain.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL.lib")
```

and always remember to properly close SDL and free resources when you are finished with it:

```
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
```

also when linking from your general include folder it is safer to use angled brackets.. ie:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

here is a small [example program](http://bpaste.net/show/eidCkSLklqjROdm3RPvY/) ..so provided the .dll is in one of the places i listed above this should work.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Dlls are in their proper place, the project is set to console, already tried with the #pragma lines before, still no luck.

Comment: did you try the example program i attached? personally i find msvc to be bloated and cumbersome when dealing with things like this, i would recommend switching to mingw if all else fails.. save me some headaches back then.

Comment: Yes, I tried your program and got the same type of errors. Thanks for the try though. "Linking" in general does work though, I tried a different library (SFML) which is very similar and has more or less the same setup (include, lib, additional includes) and it did work. So it's something SDL related.